# How to use tick() function when testing routes?

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I'am trying to run a unit test for the root component **`app.component.ts`** where **`app.component.html`** HTML just contains **`<router-outlet></router-outlet>`**

Therefore the app starts immediately on `http://localhost:port/login` using `redirectTo` based on the following router config:

```
`export const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full'},
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
    { path: 'add', component: RegisterComponent},
    ....
];
export const routes: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);`
```

My issue is when I run the **`ng test --sm=false`** with/using the following method in **`app.component.spec.ts`**:

```
it( 'navigate to "" redirects you to /login', fakeAsync(() => {
        router.navigate([""]);
        tick();
        expect(location.path()).toBe("/login");
    })
);
```

the test failed and it shows: **`Expected '' to be '/login'`** but when I use 
this method/syntax:

```
it( "root should be able to navigate to `/login`", fakeAsync(() => {
        fixture.detectChanges();
        // initial navigation
        router.navigate([""]).then(() => {
           expect(router.url).toEqual("/login");
        });
     })
);
```

then the test passes.

So, I can't really figure out what's exactly wrong with using **`tick()`** function etc. in this case.

What's exactly the best practice - try using the first method and fix the failed test or would the second function be enough for my test?

What should I change/fix in the first method to be able to use it instead of the second one?

For more input, here is the angular and angular-cli version I'am using:

```
Angular CLI: 1.5.0
Node: 8.0.0
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 5.0.3
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

@angular/cdk: 5.0.0-rc.2
@angular/cli: 1.5.0
@angular/material: 5.0.0-rc.2
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.0.33
@angular-devkit/core: 0.0.21
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.0.37
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.1.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.8.0
@schematics/angular: 0.1.7
typescript: 2.4.2
webpack: 3.8.1
```

Comment: The second method is how'd you usually run component tests. What angular and ng-cli version do you use?

Comment: @Zlatko: I have updated my question... added the info regarding angular and angular-cli version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is `tick` function doesn't wait until the promise resolves in this case. You can use `tick(2000)` or higher value to wait until the promise return but it is not accurate.

in the second function as soon as the url navigate the router resolve the promise. so you don't need to blindly set the timeout value to wait till the promise. so the second method is more accurate

Comment: That's true... it has to do with resolving promise, but the hint using `tick(2000)` didn't really help... I even used `tick(10000)`. What did help is adding the `then()` function and changing the first function to: `it( 'navigate to "" redirects you to /login', fakeAsync(() => { fixture.detectChanges();  router.navigate([""]).then(() => {  tick(); expect(location.path()).toBe("/login"); }); }) );`. In this way the test passes.

Comment: i think we don't need to use tick function since `then` is already using

Comment: That's true...  I agree. I'll go for the second method as it fixes my issue any way and it's clearer than the first one.